# ignore validation on dialog close jsf primefaces

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, dialog

Iam trying to validate a p:dialog as below

```
                                <p:dialog widgetVar="canPolDialog" id="canPolDialog" modal="true"
                                      appendTo="@form:canPolPanel"
                                      focus="name"
                                      resizable="false" draggable="false" minHeight="600" minWidth="250" width="700"
                                      onHide="hideModal()" styleClass="canPolDialog">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <div class="dialogHeader">
                                        <h2>#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.dialog.title']}</h2>
                                        <span>#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.dialog.description']}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </f:facet>

                                <p:outputPanel id="cancellationDetail"
                                               styleClass="col-md-12 xs-mt-20 dialogSublabel">
                                    <f:validateBean>
                                        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{policyBean.renderCancelationDialog}">
                                            <p:outputPanel id="customPanel">
                                                <f:verbatim escape="false"
                                                            rendered="#{policyBean.closePopup}">
                                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                                        PF('canPolDialog').hide();
                                                    </script>
                                                </f:verbatim>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <ets:inputTextWithLabel
                                                        label="pages.cancellationPolicies.name"
                                                        id="name"
                                                        formCol="6"
                                                        requiredMessage="#{readMessage.getValidationMessagesValue('cancellationPolcy.policyName.cant.be.null')}"
                                                        value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.name}"
                                                        required="true"
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-10 minsizeText">
                                                    #{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.policyName.description']}
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <ets:selectWithLabel required="true"
                                                                         id="policyNameType"
                                                                         requiredMessage="#{readMessage.getValidationMessagesValue('cancellationPolcy.policyNameType.cant.be.null')}"
                                                                         firstItem="#{messages['global.pleaseSelect']}"
                                                                         formCol="6"
                                                                         label="pages.cancellationPolicies.policyName"
                                                                         value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.policyNameType}">
                                                        <f:selectItems noSelectionValue="false"
                                                                       value="#{PolicyNameType.values()}"
                                                                       var="nameType"
                                                                       itemValue="#{nameType}"
                                                                       itemLabel="#{messages[nameType.getBundleKey()]}"/>
                                                        <p:ajax event="change" resetValues="true"
                                                                update="@form:cancellationTypePanel,@form:dropdownHour,@form:penaltyRenderArea,@form:noShowPanel"
                                                                listener="#{policyBean.onNameTypeChange()}"/>
                                                    </ets:selectWithLabel>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-10 minsizeText">
                                                    #{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.acceptCancelation.description']}
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <p:outputPanel id="cancellationTypePanel">
                                                        <ets:selectWithLabel
                                                            id="cancellationType"
                                                            firstItem="#{messages['global.pleaseSelect']}"
                                                            formCol="6" required="true"
                                                            requiredMessage="#{readMessage.getValidationMessagesValue('cancellationPolicy.canType.cant.be.null')}"
                                                            label="pages.cancellationPolicies.acceptCancelation"
                                                            value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.cancellationType}">
                                                            <f:selectItems
                                                                value="#{policyBean.cancellationTypes}"
                                                                var="var" noSelectionValue="false"
                                                                itemValue="#{var}"
                                                                itemLabel="#{messages['cancelationPolicyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.'.concat(var.friendlyName())]}"
                                                            />
                                                            <p:ajax resetValues="true" event="change"
                                                                    listener="#{policyBean.handleCancellationChange}"
                                                                    update="@form:dropdownHour,@form:penaltyRenderArea"/>
                                                        </ets:selectWithLabel>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                    <p:outputPanel id="dropdownHour">
                                                        <p:outputPanel
                                                            rendered="#{policyBean.renderSameDayCanpolOpt}">
                                                            <ets:selectWithLabel
                                                                id="cancellationValue"
                                                                value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.cancellationValue}"
                                                                formCol="6" required="true"
                                                                requiredMessage="#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.pleaseSelectHour']}"
                                                                label="pages.cancellationPolicies.sameday">
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="00:00"
                                                                              itemValue="00:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="01:00"
                                                                              itemValue="01:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="02:00"
                                                                              itemValue="02:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="03:00"
                                                                              itemValue="03:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="04:00"
                                                                              itemValue="04:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="05:00"
                                                                              itemValue="05:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="06:00"
                                                                              itemValue="06:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="07:00"
                                                                              itemValue="07:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="08:00"
                                                                              itemValue="08:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="09:00"
                                                                              itemValue="09:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="10:00"
                                                                              itemValue="10:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="11:00"
                                                                              itemValue="11:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="12:00"
                                                                              itemValue="12:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="13:00"
                                                                              itemValue="13:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="14:00"
                                                                              itemValue="14:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="15:00"
                                                                              itemValue="15:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="16:00"
                                                                              itemValue="16:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="17:00"
                                                                              itemValue="17:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="18:00"
                                                                              itemValue="18:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="19:00"
                                                                              itemValue="19:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="20:00"
                                                                              itemValue="20:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="21:00"
                                                                              itemValue="21:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="22:00"
                                                                              itemValue="22:00"/>
                                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="23:00"
                                                                              itemValue="23:00"/>
                                                            </ets:selectWithLabel>
                                                        </p:outputPanel>

                                                        <p:outputPanel
                                                            rendered="#{policyBean.renderDaysBeforeCheckinOpt}"
                                                            formCol="6">
                                                            <ets:inputNumberWithLabel decimalPlaces="0"
                                                                                      required="true"
                                                                                      requiredMessage="#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.pleaseAdaysbeforecheckin']}"
                                                                                      label="pages.cancellationPolicies.adaysbeforecheckin"
                                                                                      minValue="0"
                                                                                      formCol="6"
                                                                                      maxValue="30"
                                                                                      styleClass="number-form-control"
                                                                                      id="adaysbeforecheckin"
                                                                                      value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.daysBeforeCheckinValue}">
                                                                <p:ajax event="blur"
                                                                        update="adaysbeforecheckin"/>
                                                            </ets:inputNumberWithLabel>
                                                        </p:outputPanel>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                </div>

                                                <div
                                                    class="col-md-10 minsizeText">#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.penaltyCharge.description']}

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <p:outputPanel id="penaltyRenderArea">
                                                        <p:outputPanel>
                                                            <ets:selectWithLabel
                                                                id="penaltyType" required="true"
                                                                requiredMessage="#{readMessage.getValidationMessagesValue('cancellationPolcy.penType.cant.be.null')}"
                                                                label="pages.cancellationPolicies.penaltyCharge"
                                                                formCol="6"
                                                                firstItem="#{messages['global.pleaseSelect']}"
                                                                value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.penaltyType}"
                                                                disabled="#{policyBean.penaltyDisable}">
                                                                <f:selectItems
                                                                    value="#{policyBean.penaltyTypeList}"
                                                                    var="var"
                                                                    itemValue="#{var}"
                                                                    itemLabel="#{messages['cancelationPolicyBean.penalty.'.concat(var.friendlyName())]}"
                                                                />
                                                                <p:ajax event="change"
                                                                        listener="#{policyBean.handlePenaltyChange}"
                                                                        resetValues="true"
                                                                        update="@form:dropDownPenalty"/>
                                                            </ets:selectWithLabel>


                                                            <p:outputPanel id="dropDownPenalty">
                                                                <p:outputPanel
                                                                    rendered="#{policyBean.renderPenaltyTotalPrice}">
                                                                    <ets:inputNumberWithLabel
                                                                        formCol="6" required="true"
                                                                        requiredMessage="#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.penaltyValueOfTotalPrice']}"
                                                                        label="pages.cancellationPolicies.ofTotalPrice"
                                                                        value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.penaltyValueOfTotalPrice}"
                                                                        symbol="%"
                                                                        decimalPlaces="0"
                                                                        emptyValue="empty"
                                                                        minValue="0"
                                                                        id="penaltyValueOfTotalPrice"
                                                                        styleClass="number-form-control"
                                                                        maxValue="100">
                                                                        <p:ajax event="blur"
                                                                                update="penaltyValueOfTotalPrice"/>
                                                                    </ets:inputNumberWithLabel>
                                                                </p:outputPanel>
                                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                                        </p:outputPanel>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                </div>

                                                <div
                                                    class="col-md-10 minsizeText">#{messages['pages.cancellationPolicies.noShow.description']}
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <p:outputPanel id="noShowPanel">
                                                        <ets:selectWithLabel
                                                            id="policyNoShowType"
                                                            label="pages.cancellationPolicies.noShow"
                                                            requiredMessage="#{readMessage.getValidationMessagesValue('cancellationPolcy.noshow.cant.be.null')}"
                                                            firstItem="#{messages['global.pleaseSelect']}"
                                                            required="true"
                                                             formCol="6" event="change"
                                                            value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyPojo.policyNoShowType}">
                                                            <f:selectItems
                                                                value="#{policyBean.cancelationPolicyNoShowTypes}"
                                                                var="var" itemValue="#{var}"
                                                                itemLabel="#{messages['cancelationPolicyBean.noshow.'.concat(var.friendlyName())]}"/>
                                                        </ets:selectWithLabel>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="dialog-footer">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <ets:submitButton value="#{messages['global.save']}"
                                                                              update="@form:canDatatable,@form:cancellationDetail,@form:messages,@form:content"
                                                                              ajax="true"
                                                                              process="@form:canPolPanel"
                                                                              styleClass="btn-info btn pull-right"
                                                                              action="#{policyBean.saveCancellPolicy()}">
                                                            </ets:submitButton>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <p:ajax event="close"
                                                        process="@this"
                                                        resetValues="true">


                                                </p:ajax>

                                            </p:outputPanel>

                                        </p:outputPanel>
                                    </f:validateBean>
                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </p:dialog>
```

when i submit dialog without filling inputs the validations are executing correctly after that if I close the dialog (gave up, dont want to save modal) because of executed and fail validations I cannot submit parent form due to this issue. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your parent form and your dialog are part of the same `<h:form>` you have to take care of the `process` attributes of your ajax behaviors. If you process the whole form the input fields in your dialog are also processed even if the dialog is not shown. So take care that you only process the fields outside the dialog.

You could also place your dialog in an own `<h:form>` (not within the other `<h:form>`), e.g.

```
<h:form id="form">
   parent form
</h:form>

<h:form id="dialog-form">
   <p:dialog ...>
      dialog form
   </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Then you can use `@form` within each form. If you want to `process` or `update` the other form you can use absolute ids, e.g. ":form" or ":dialog-form".